# How to verify a linearly dependent list of vectors in $F^3$ by finding the scalars

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studing Linear Algebra and reading "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler.

Example $2.20$ says

$(2,3,1),(1,-1,2),(7,3,8)$ is linearly dependent in $F^3$ because

$2(2,3,1)+3(1,-1,2)+(-1)(7,3,8)=(0,0,0)$

Then we know that it is linearly dependent because it has scalars not all $0.$
But how do we find these scalars?

I've tried to make a matrix and do some row operation, but when the solution to the equation is $0,$ I don't quiet understand how to solve, and find the scalars.

Can any one help?

Comment: you want to solve $\begin{pmatrix}2&1&7\\3&-1&3\\1&2&8\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Like @J.W.Tanner said. Maybe also take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Evaluating_linear_independence)

Comment: If you were to row reduce $\begin{bmatrix}2&1&7\\3&-1&3\\1&2&8\end{bmatrix}$ you will [wind up with](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B2%2C1%2C7%7D%2C%7B3%2C-1%2C3%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C8%7D%7D) $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&\color{red}{2}\\0&1&\color{red}{3}\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.  Notice the $2$ and the $3$ there.  Try to generalize.

Comment: You can also solve it for the first two coordinates, and check that the 3rd coordinates satisfies the same or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row reduce the following coefficient matrix (where the columns are the given vectors) and solve for when the variables in each row sum to $0$:

$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&7\\3&-1&3\\1&2&8\end{bmatrix}$.

In reduced row echelon form, the matrix is

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\0&1&3\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve this system:

$$2x+y+7z=0\tag1$$
$$3x-y+3z=0\tag2$$
$$x+2y+8z=0\tag3.$$

To eliminate $y$, add (1) and (2) to get $$5x+10z=0.\tag4$$

To eliminate $x$, subtract (1) from twice (3) to get $3y+9z=0$ or $$y+3z=0.\tag5$$

$z$ is arbitrary; take, for example, $z=1$, and then see from (4) that $x=-2$ and from (5) that $y=-3$.

---

Note that if $(x,y,z)$ works, then so does any multiple of $(x,y,z)$.

In particular, the coefficients given here are $-1$ times those given in the question.